# Why does incrementing one array, increment another?

Tags: c++, arrays, increment

I am having a problem with incrementing a single item in an array. It ends up incrementing another array.. How does it do this? this is what I have:

```
string simulateFIFO(darray<int> requests, int frameSize) {

string results;

int currentPages[frameSize];
int timer[frameSize];

int hits = 0;
int faults = 0;

cout << "STARTING FIFO" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {
    cout << requests[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) {
    currentPages[i] = -1;
    timer[i] = 0;
}

// Start Calculations
for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {

    bool requestSet = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < frameSize; j++) {

        if (currentPages[j] < 0) {
            // Current frame does not have a page
            cout << "FRAME IS EMPTY" << endl;

            currentPages[j] = requests[i];

            requestSet = true;
            faults++;

            j = frameSize;
        }
        else if (currentPages[j] == requests[i]) {
            cout << "FRAME IS SAME AS REQUEST" << endl;
            // Current Frame is set the the page being requested

            timer[j] = 0;

            requestSet = true;
            hits++;

            j = frameSize;
        }

        cout << currentPages[j] << endl;

        timer[j]++;

        cout << currentPages[j] << endl;

    }

    // Check to see if a request was set or not
    if (requestSet == false) {
        cout << "FRAME NEEDS REPLACED" << endl;
        // The request wasnt set. Determine which frame to replace with the new request
        int lastUsed = 0;
        int lastUsedIndex = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < frameSize; j++) {

            if (timer[j] > lastUsed) {
                lastUsed = timer[j];
                lastUsedIndex = j;
            }
        }

        currentPages[lastUsedIndex] = requests[i];
        //timer[lastUsedIndex] = 0;

        faults++;
    }

    cout << "HEY 3: " << currentPages[0] << endl;

    cout << "NEW FRAME: ";
    for (int j = 0; j < frameSize; j++) {
        cout << currentPages[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

}

cout << "FIFO" << endl;
cout << faults << endl;
cout << hits << endl;
cout << endl;

return results;
```

}

My Output ends up being

```
0
1
```

Why does increasing one array actually increase the other as well?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By modifying the code in a way, that it would compile, I can't reproduce the problem. As Anon Mail suggested, please post a [mcve].

Comment: `int currentPages[frameSize];` is illegal in ISO C++. If this compiles then you're relying on a compiler extension, which could do anything really.  But it seems likely that in the `...` you omit some invocation of undefined behaviour, e.g. `j` gets changed to be outside the loop bounds

Comment: The only part I print is where is before and after i do timer[j]++, and that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Anon Mail, it was the most simple way I could put it.

Comment: I tried making it as simple as possible, but apparently I can't get any simpler. Ill just post the whole thing

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong web site. This is not the web site where anyone can post a completely confusing, convoluted, and incomplete question, and then expect someone to figure out the answer without expecting you to provide additional information that clarifies your problem.

Comment: how is int currentPages[frameSize] illegal?

Comment: @M.M: You win a prize, I see `j = frameSize;` in two places followed by printing and _modifying_ array elements. Post an answer.

Comment: @TannerJuby The array size should equate to being constant expression (i.e. value known at compile time), since the size of your arrays are a parameter passed to the function, they are definitely not known at compile time.

Comment: j=frameSize is a red herring. The first for-loop initializes the entire currentPages array to -1. Therefore, the if statement inside the second loop should end up incrementing the faults value, which the purported output does not show as have happened. But, yes, all the other problems with the question makes it impossible to figure out the answer. Not to mention that the shown output does not come even close to matching the expected output from the shown code. Voting to close it.

Comment: Although [gcc will allow it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: gcc allows that as a language extension, many people use it without realizing it's not standard C++.

Comment: ah shoot! I did that to exit the loop. I put that after the increment now and it works properly! Thanks guys

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh really? Didn't use it since university, so I can't remember what it supports. When using OPs code in MSVC it informed me straight away that it requires constant expression (and I expected it to complain on, at least, that place).

Comment: @TannerJuby You can write `break` to exit the loop prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code includes a possible path of execution:

```
j = frameSize;
```

followed by

```
timer[j]++;
```

This accesses out of bounds: for an array of dimension `frameSize`, the valid indices are `0` through `frameSize-1`.

I guess you actually want to exit the loop; if so then replace `j = frameSize;` with `break;` .

NB. `int timer[frameSize];` is not permitted in ISO C++; array bounds must be known at compile-time. Your code is relying on a compiler extension.